# Wamp wont to start

Tags: php, xampp, wampserver

I installed XAMPP several months ago. It works ok. But now I have to install WAMPSERVER. I installed it but WAMPSERVER won't to start. It shows error: Unable to load dynamic library D:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll - the specified module could not be found.
I remove path to xampp php folder from system environment PATH, but it did not help. Where path to XAMPP php it saved ?

Thanks

Comment: it will best to uninstall existing XAMPP completely before installing WAMP as they might conflict

Comment: ok, now it works correctly